# Java JNI method id caching

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I want to cache method IDs across calls. For this I get method IDs:

```
// Put static to clarify it's saved across calls.
static jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(class_HelloWorld, name, signature);
```

My question is: do I need to make `class_HelloWorld` a global ref with `NewGlobalRef` or method IDs can be obtained from local ref and saved (I get `class_HelloWorld` using `FindClass`) without need for global ref-ing the class metadata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the class you got the methodID from doesn't change, you can re-use the methodID. It isn't like a `jclass` or `jobject` that needs to be cached as a `GlobalRef`: it's just an integer really.

Comment: The answer appears to be straight to the point, but how can classes possibly change? Java is not dynamic language and as far as I know it's not possible to modify class definition to add or remove methods. As I understand the question terms, there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13940735/213871) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19657117/213871) that also cache references to classes when the actual question was just how to cache method/field ids to reuse later. So the question really is: will method/fields ids be valid for all the duration of the program even without class caching?

Comment: @certko Yes they will.