# JNI convert a String to char *, returned by an instance method

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

in my program C is called from Java, C functions can be called outside of a Java context but sometimes need some Java ressources. I should explain what the program is... So the C library is a plugin system which can load C plugins, plugins sometimes need to access to Java ressources, for example to retrieve a String id.

So when the plugin system is loaded, an init function is called by the JNI so the `JNIEnv *` and `jobject` can be stored for further access by the plugins.

In the java class I have provided instance method to access to those ressources, for example I have method

```
private String getId() {
  return "Bryan";
}
```

The C plugin system have a function

```
char *get_id(char *id) {
  jobject jobj = (*jvm.env)->CallObjectMethod(jvm.env, jvm.this, jvm.getId);
  jstring jid = jobj;
  if (jid == NULL) 
    debug("get_id", RED "jid NULL");
   else 
     debug("get_id", RED "jid not null"); */
  debug("get_id", RED "in get_id, method called");
  const char *cid = (*jvm.env)->GetStringUTFChars(jvm.env, jid, NULL);
  debug("get_id", RED "converted to c string: %s", cid);
  strcpy(id, cid);
  debug("get_id", RED "string copied");
  (*jvm.env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jvm.env, jid, cid);
  debug("get_id", RED "string released");
  return id;
}
```

Where jvm is a structure containing the field `env` and `obj` corresponding to the `JNIEnv *` and `jobject` stored at initialization, and `jvm.getId` which is the `methodID` of the `getId` Java instance method inizialized at the same time.
The debug macro is just a call to `printf` with a `flush` which help me to debug the program.

And that is the output after a call to `get_id`:

```
DEBUG IN plugin_system.c LINE 339:
In get_id
in get_id, calling method...
DEBUG IN plugin_system.c LINE 343:
In get_id
jid NULL
DEBUG IN plugin_system.c LINE 346:
In get_id
in get_id, method called
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb6bcb6cd70, pid=25254, tid=0x00007fb6974be700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x675d70]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/kowa/code/reseaux/projet/ringo/java/bin/core or core.25254
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/kowa/code/reseaux/projet/ringo/java/bin/hs_err_pid25254.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
[4]    25254 abort (core dumped)  java Jring Nick 9999 8888 1
```

As you can see the call to Java `getId` is (looks) successfull, but a core dump is triggered by `GetStringUTFChars`.

What's wrong ?

Comment: What is your `jvm` object?  A structure?  A class?  How do you fill it in?  In general, you can't cache values such the JVM `env` value.  Nor can you cache objects or method ids unless you create a [global reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112603/what-is-jni-global-reference).

Comment: It's a `struct jvm { JNIEnv * env; jobject this; jclass thisClass; methodID getId; };`, the field are filled after the loading of the library, after a java call to a native init function.

Comment: First off, which character set and encoding are you using for the C strings, the system default or a specific one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not cache the JVM's `env`.  See [Keeping a global reference to the JNIEnv environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420463/keeping-a-global-reference-to-the-jnienv-environment), especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12421377/4756299):

> The JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv) is valid only in the current
>   thread. Should another thread need to access the Java VM, it must
>   first call AttachCurrentThread() to attach itself to the VM and obtain
>   a JNI interface pointer. Once attached to the VM, a native thread
>   works just like an ordinary Java thread running inside a native
>   method. The native thread remains attached to the VM until it calls
>   DetachCurrentThread() to detach itself.

[Updated link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html).  The link in the other answer is stale.

As far as the Java object, class, and method id, you need to [obtain a global reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#global_local) to those if you're going to cache them.  See [What is 'JNI Global reference'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112603/what-is-jni-global-reference) and [Caching JNI objects and thread-safety (in Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893089/caching-jni-objects-and-thread-safety-in-android)

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about that. I've modified the code so now the structure contains only a pointer to the JVM and a global reference to the object. Each time I call the JNI from "a pure C context", I call `AttachCurrentThread` before. I still get an error: `JNIEnv *env;  jint rs = (*jvm.jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm.jvm, &env, NULL);  assert(rs == JNI_OK);  rs = (*jvm.jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm.jvm);  assert (rs == JNI_OK);
`, the assert is triggered by the call to `DetachCurrentThread`...

Comment: What do you mean by "a pure C context"?  Per the [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html):  "A native thread attached to the VM must call DetachCurrentThread() to detach itself before exiting. A thread cannot detach itself if there are Java methods on the call stack."  You may not need to call `DetachCurrentThread()`.  Print out the value of `env` in your initial JNI function that kicks off the loading of your plugin, and then again where you call `DetachCurrentThread()`.  It might be the same because it's the same thread.